# Floating action buttons overlap

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I wanted to have two floating action buttons (FABs) but currently the buttons overlap, what I want to achieve is to show both floating action buttons on top of each other like the picture below.

This is probably a recurring question, but I didn't find any solution to vuetify

[image]

This is my code:

```html
<v-btn fab bottom fixed right dark color="primary"></v-btn>
<v-btn fab bottom fixed small right dark color="secondary"></v-btn>
```

Vuetify version: 2.1.11

Comment: you could add `style="bottom:64px"` to one of them

Comment: Or add a margin class on one of them if you don't want to use styles.

Comment: @Billion, I don't think vuetify comes with a `mb-16` class - which you would need for 64 pixels :p - assuming you need 64 pixels of course - depending on the size of the FAB

Answer (score 2):

You could put them together in a fixed container like the `v-navigation-drawer`...

```
  <v-navigation-drawer stateless permanent floating fixed right>
        <v-btn fab dark color="primary" class="mb-2">
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn fab dark color="secondary">
        </v-btn>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/YbLdVWxc0z)